# How to customize hosts file in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, hosts-file

We have an app that is getting deployed through EBS (on tomcat) and every now and then we are getting an error:

```
unable to resolve host ip-172-30-0-167
```

This causes other issues. 
As far as I am aware, one of the ways to solve it is by updating the hosts file and with an entry that points `ip-172-30-0-167` to real IP address of the server.

My question is, how can I add an entry to hosts file on deployment? I didn't find anything related to it through .ebsextensions.

Maybe there is another way to solve it.

**UPDATE**

One of the issues that I have is with sending emails:

```
ERROR g.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder: Failed to send email
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:  org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:  . Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:417) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender$send$0.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder$_sendMessage_closure1.doCall(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:124) [mail-2.0.0.RC6.jar:na]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder$_sendMessage_closure1.doCall(MailMessageBuilder.groovy) [mail-2.0.0.RC6.jar:na]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:507) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:  Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1481) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.helo(SMTPTransport.java:917) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:417) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345) ~[javax.mail-api-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:486) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:406) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    ... 22 common frames omitted
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:  ERROR g.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder: Failed to send email
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:  org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:  . Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:417) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender$send$0.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder$_sendMessage_closure1.doCall(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:124) [mail-2.0.0.RC6.jar:na]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at grails.plugins.mail.MailMessageBuilder$_sendMessage_closure1.doCall(MailMessageBuilder.groovy) [mail-2.0.0.RC6.jar:na]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:507) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:  Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1481) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.helo(SMTPTransport.java:917) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:417) ~[mail-1.4.1.jar:1.4.1]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345) ~[javax.mail-api-1.5.1.jar:1.5.1]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:486) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:406) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
Jan 27 15:40:30 unknown staging:    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

and it looks like on deployment the proposed approach didn't help:

```
ERROR net.sf.ehcache.Cache: Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID. Cause was: ip-172-35-11-183: ip-172-35-11-183: Name or service not known
Jan 27 15:35:25 unknown staging:  java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-172-35-11-183: ip-172-35-11-183: Name or service not known
Jan 27 15:35:25 unknown staging:    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
Jan 27 15:35:25 unknown staging:    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<clinit>(Cache.java:200) ~[ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar:na]
Jan 27 15:35:25 unknown staging:    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:302) [ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar:na]
Jan 27 15:35:25 unknown staging:    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createDefaultCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:218) [ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar:na]
Jan 27 15:35:25 unknown staging:    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:599) [ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar:na]
Jan 27 15:35:25 unknown staging:    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:358) [ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar:na]
```

Comment: That is always an error on Tomcat Elastic Beanstalks - what issue is it causing?

Comment: In our case, seems like the email sending is choking + sometimes nginx proxy needs to be restarted after deployment.

Comment: @stdunbar So, it seems like the approach didn't really help. see the update on a post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I said that it was common and then looked into some other code and found that I'm setting the hostname in .ebextensions.  I have something like:

```
01_command:
    echo 127.0.0.1 `hostname` >> /etc/hosts"
```

to add a hostname.  Note that I'm not sending email so I'm not sure if you need the real hostname.  If you do that could be changed to:

```
01_command:
    echo `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4` `hostname` >> /etc/hosts"
```

The ultimate problem is that the Elastic Beanstalk sets the hostname to something that is not in /etc/hosts as you said.

Comment: This solution has couple of issues. I need to know the internal IP for that, which I don't (well, not always). + It will do this on every deployment, so I'll end up with bunch of these entries. As for your last question, I didn't say that is sets anything in not hosts file. I think it leaves it as is from the bare bones ubuntu image.

Comment: The curl command gets you the internal IP (the private IP).  You're right - my deployment process takes down all instances and spins up new ones so if you reuse the instances you'll get multiple entries.  That won't actually hurt anything but it's arguably not correct.

Comment: Another question though: what is this: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 ?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html - Elastic Beanstalk machines are just EC2's.

Comment: But for that I still need to know the private IP, right?

Comment: That's what the curl statement gives you - the "local-ipv4" address.  Try it.

Comment: So, what is this IP then? `169.254.169.254`

Comment: Take a look at the docs I linked to - it is a linked local address.

Comment: This approach didn't seem to help

Comment: Just validated the if I set everything in hosts file, all works as expected. However, the approach with doing it on deployment like you proposed, is not really working. Nothing is getting added into the hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by **enableDnsHostnames** parameter in your VPC config.

Take a look at [AWS error - sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-0-xx-xx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441873)

Thanks!