# Rabbitmq AutoCluster using AWS autoscale group backend is unable to connect to other nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, dns, rabbitmq

```
RabbitMQ 3.6.6 on Erlang 19.1.3
```

When autocluster plugin interrogates aws autoscale group, it retrieves the value of private dns field something like `ip-10-80-x-xx`.

The hostname of box is `node1` for example.

Then it tries to connect to `ip-10-80-10-243` which won't resolve.

Running manually `rabbitmqctl join_cluster ip-192-168-x-xx` fails.

However, running manually `rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@10.80.10.243` it connects.

I don't seem to be able to change `ip-10-80-x-xx` as that is something that amazon sets internally.

All of these nodes instances are on an internal private subnet.

```
=INFO REPORT==== 28-Mar-2017::23:14:23 ===
autocluster: Discovered ['rabbit@ip-10-80-10-144','rabbit@ip-10-80-10-243']

=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Mar-2017::23:14:23 ===
autocluster: Can not communicate with cluster nodes.
```

Anyone know how to make `rabbitmq` to start with different hostname for example `rabbit@privateip` instead of `rabbit@ip-10-80-10-144` ?

I want to use RabbitMQ cluster based on autoscaling rule where nodes can go up and down, so I will not be able to add every time that node goes up the internal dns `ip-192-168-x-xx` to `/etc/hosts` to all hosts in order to resolve the private dns for example:

```
127.0.0.1 node2 ip-10-80-10-243.eu-central-1.compute.internal ip-10-80-10-243
10.80.10.144 node1 ip-10-80-10-144.eu-central-1.compute.internal ip-10-80-10-144
10.80.10.243 node2 ip-10-80-10-243.eu-central-1.compute.internal ip-10-80-10-243
```

Comment: *Then it tries to connect to ip-10-80-10-243 which won't resolve.*  Sounds like you don't have the necessary features enabled in your VPC -- DNS Support and DNS Hostnames.  [Check that](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-hostnames)?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I want to be able to change node name from `rabbit@ip-10-80-10-144` to `rabbit@private.ip`.
are you sure is it possible to ping to private dns something like ip-10-80-x-xx ?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely possible, if the VPC is configured correctly.  See the link in my prior comment, and [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33443018/1695906).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have managed to fix the vpc configuration and everything works, do you like to answer and I will mark the answer as accepted ?